# assign struct with char array inside using "=" works?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

I am reviewing someone's code and the developer has assigned one struct to another. The struct contains a char array. Somehow that "works", meaning the char array from struct A does get copied to struct B (not by reference). I'm totally baffled. Can s.o. explain that to me? I have written up a little program to illustrate the "problem".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/**************************************
 * some define and typedef for later
 **************************************/
#define MAX_LEN (80)

typedef struct month_s
{
    char name[MAX_LEN];
} month_st;

/**************************************
 * This bit is clear.
 **************************************/
static void usingString()
{
    char mCur[MAX_LEN] = {"Jan"};
    char mNext[MAX_LEN] = {"Feb"};

    /** this doesn't compile (of course) */
    //mCur = mNext;

    /** we need a pointer/reference */
    char *pmCur = &mCur[0];

    /** however now we "copy by reference"...*/
    pmCur = &(mNext[0]);

    /** ...so this change also applies to pmCur*/
    strcpy(mNext, "Mar");

    /** ...so pmCur is now "Mar"*/
    printf("%s: %s\n", __func__, pmCur);
}

/**************************************
 * I though the same/s.th. similar
 * as above happens here. But this "works".
 * I'm surprised to see that not to be
 * the case. Can someone explain?
 **************************************/
static void usingStruct()
{
    month_st mCur = {"Jan"};
    month_st mNext = {"Feb"};

    /** I would have thought this is "copy by reference" for the string! */
    mCur = mNext;

    /** I would have thought this also overrides mCur.name
            'cause it's pointing to mNext.name now */
    strcpy(mNext.name, "Mar");

    /** how come this works??? mCur.name is still "Feb"*/
    printf("%s: %s\n", __func__, mCur.name);
}
/**************************************
 * just the main()
 **************************************/
int main()
{
    usingString();
    usingStruct();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see three explanations about the difference between pointers and arrays, but they don't seem to address the question being asked, as I understand it.

The question, as I understand it, is: "I know that I can't assign one array to another, so why *can* I do it if the array is inside a struct?"

The answer is, basically, "because the language said so". Even though a struct is an aggregate type, and may very well contain an array, the language spec says that structs are assignable, and therefore structs are assignable. This is section `6.5.16.1 Simple assignment` in both [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

<sub>(Under the hood, the compiler may have to implement a memory copy, but that's the compiler's problem, not yours.)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

What you are probably most astonished about is that arrays and pointers are not the same thing in C. An array member as in your example contains not only a pointer to the string but the string itself. Thus all theses are copied when you assign one `struct` instance to the other.

Answer (score 3):

According to your declaration of struct:

```
typedef struct month_s
{
    char name[MAX_LEN];
} month_st;
```

`sizeof(month_st)` includes spaces for char array that is member of structs.(Notice you are doing static memory allocation, `name` is not pointer but array).
So when you assign one strct variable to other variable it completely copy array(or we can say total `sizeof(month_st))` bytes will be copied).

Next, your are declaring two struct variables:

```
month_st mCur = {"Jan"};
month_st mNext = {"Feb"};
```

Memories for both variables `mCur` and `mNext` are different. When you do assignment `nCur = mNext;`, values of `mNext`  copies to `nCur` struct variable's memory but both have separate (thier-own) memory.

`strcpy()` statement:

```
strcpy(mNext, "Mar");
```

effecting only variable `mNext`, it don't change content of variable `nCur`.

For your confusion, Suppose if you have declared your struct as follows:

```
typedef struct month_s
{
    char* name;
} month_st;
```

Still by doing `nCur = mNext;`  you copy `sizeof(month_st))` bytes from `mNext` to `nCur` variable hence to only address copied as `name` is a pointer to a memory.

In this case complete array/memory (that you probably allocate dynamically) not copy this is called **Shallow copy**.

Comment: There is no ***Shadow Copy*** there is a ***Shallow copy***.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused because you think `mCur` and `mNext` are pointers to objects, while in fact they are objects. The struct `month_s` merely allocates space in memory for storing the month name. It does not allocate memory for storing a pointer to anything. Thus, when `mCur` is assigned the value of `mNext`, the entire object is copied as it is copied by value and not by reference.

I have annotated your code for convenience:

```
static void usingStruct()
{
    month_st mCur = {"Jan"};
    month_st mNext = {"Feb"};

    /** mCur and mNext are both objects. Assigning one to the other 
      * will copy by value and not by reference (as there is no reference
      * to be copied in the first place). After this assignment, 
      * mCur == {"Feb"}  */
    mCur = mNext;

    /** mNext.name is the address of the memory allocated to the object
      * mNext. This line copies the characters "Mar" to the first three
      * bytes of this memory allocation */
    strcpy(mNext.name, "Mar");

    /** At this point, mCur == {"Feb"} and mNext == {"Mar"} */
    printf("%s: %s\n", __func__, mCur.name);
}
```